# Establecer un rango de semanas con totales para una Consulta POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql, datatables

que tal, buenas noches comunidad, el motivo de este mensaje es porque me gustaría obtener su ayuda en una Query que estoy realizando y me he bloqueado un poco.

a continuación lo que he avanzado:

```
SELECT cosecha_divisiones_rancho.division_rancho_id,divisiones_rancho.nombre, SUM(detalles_cosecha.cantidad),cosecha.fecha_cosecha
FROM public.divisiones_de_rancho as divisiones_rancho
INNER JOIN public.ranchos as rancho ON divisiones_rancho.rancho_id=rancho.id
INNER JOIN public.cosechas_divisiones_ranchos as cosecha_divisiones_rancho ON divisiones_rancho.id = cosecha_divisiones_rancho.division_rancho_id
INNER JOIN public.cosechas as cosecha ON cosecha.id = cosecha_divisiones_rancho.cosecha_id
INNER JOIN public.cosechas_detalles as detalles_cosecha ON detalles_cosecha.cosecha_id = cosecha.id
INNER JOIN public.ciclos_de_cultivo as cc ON cc.id = cosecha.ciclo_cultivo_id
INNER JOIN public.variedades as variedad on variedad.id = cc.variedad_id
WHERE rancho.nombre = 'XXXXXXXX' AND divisiones_rancho.nombre = 'DIVISIÓN 3'
group by  cosecha_divisiones_rancho.division_rancho_id,divisiones_rancho.nombre,cosecha.fecha_cosecha;
```

Esto me ha dado como resultado lo siguiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien, lo que busco, es agregar una columna que determine la semana en la cual esta establecida la fecha de cosecha.

Ejemplo.

Week             total
Semana 1  |     200.00
Semana 2  |     200.00

Obviamente basado en las fechas que están en las columnas de **fecha_cosecha.**

Les agradecería muchísimo la ayuda. He estado leyendo que se puede con el DATE_PART y sigo haciendo mis intentos pero si puedo obtener ayuda, seria muy bien recibida.

BASE DE DATOS EN POSTGRESQL.

Answer (score 0):

Podés usar DATE_PART() como bien indicaste:

```
 DATE_PART('week', fecha_cosecha) AS semana
```

Le podés concatenar la palabra "semana" en la misma columna si así lo deseas.

Leé la documentación de la función [DATA_PART](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-datetime.html) para tener claro como calcula las semanas. El primer jueves del año está en la semana 1 (por lo que los primeros días del año pueden pertenecer a la última semana del año anterior).

Según la documentación de Postgresql:

week:

The number of the ISO 8601 week-numbering week of the year. By definition, ISO weeks start on Mondays and the first week of a year contains January 4 of that year. In other words, the first Thursday of a year is in week 1 of that year.

In the ISO week-numbering system, it is possible for early-January dates to be part of the 52nd or 53rd week of the previous year, and for late-December dates to be part of the first week of the next year. For example, 2005-01-01 is part of the 53rd week of year 2004, and 2006-01-01 is part of the 52nd week of year 2005, while 2012-12-31 is part of the first week of 2013. It's recommended to use the isoyear field together with week to get consistent results.